# .htaccess url rewrite but nothing happens

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Im currently trying to rewrite the urls of my new site by writing im my .htaccess. ive done redirects for 3 different scenarios and a generel.

The urls doesnt get redirect for nice url.

rewriting this url "http://domain.dk/?fag=1&id=87" to: "http://domain.dk/fag/1/id/87"

rewriting this url "http://domain.dk/?fag=1" to: "http://domain.dk/fag/1/"

rewriting this url "http://domain.dk/?id=87" to: "http://domain.dk/id/87"

my code is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.dk$ [NC]

ErrorDocument 400 /?fejl=400

ErrorDocument 401 /?fejl=401

ErrorDocument 403 /?fejl=403

ErrorDocument 404 /?fejl=404

ErrorDocument 500 /?fejl=500

RewriteRule fag/(.*)/aflevering/(.*)/ index.php?fag=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule fag/(.*)/ index.php?fag=$1
RewriteRule aflevering/(.*)/ index.php?id=$2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the AllowOverride directive set to All for the container

Comment: Have your sysadmin add the directive then.

Comment: yes i think so because i can have url rewreite when wordpress is installed.